# Extract certain values from a line with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, slice

for a school course we are learning advanced python,to get a first idea about web scraping and similar stuff.... I got an exercise to do where I have to extract the values v1, v2 from the following line of an HTML... I tried looking up but couldn't find any really specific things.... If it is unappropriated for SO just delete it....

The HTML part

```
{"v1":"first","ex":"first_soup","foo":"0","doo":"0","v1":["second"]}
```

so afterwards when i want to show the values it should look like

```
print(v1)
first
print(v2)
second
```

I tried to get the values just by slicing the whole line like this:

```
v1=htmltext[7,12]
v2=htmltext[60,66]
```

but in this case I am not using the bs4 module, which is recommended using... I would be very grateful in case someone could teach me...

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is not an HTML file but a JSON. In this case it makes no sense to use BeautifulSoup's HTML parser, you may want to use a standard [JSON library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to do that, like so:

```
import json
json_Dict=json.loads(str(soup))
```

Then you can index it using the headers (or keys)

```
json_Dict["v1"]
>>>"first"
```